# How to add custom PHP code in post header?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, conditional-tags

In header.php i want to add :

**1. For home page :**

```
link rel="alternate" href="/fr/" hreflang="fr-FR"
```

**2. For custom single post :**

```
link rel="alternate" href="/fr/category/post-name/" hreflang="fr-FR"
```

What code will be use for this ?

Comment: See here wordpress has some conditional tag that will help you to do what you want https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 0):

Please try like

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
    //IF HOME PAGE
}

if ( is_singular('YOUR-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE-HERE') ) {
  // FOR SINGLE PAGE STUFF
}
```

Please make sure you have to replace **YOUR-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE-HERE** with your **Custom post type**.

Please let me know if any query.

Thanks!

Comment: `is_home()` isn't appropriate for what they want to do. If they have a separate blog page, like `/blog/` then the alternate URL would be `/fr/blog/`, but if they used your code to output the code from their question the alternate page for `/blog/` would be set to `/fr/`.

Comment: I tired this but no result.
<?php
 
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() )
 {
    //IF HOME PAGE
    
<link rel="alternate" href="/fr/" hreflang="fr-FR">

}

if ( is_singular('movie') )
 {
  
// FOR SINGLE PAGE STUFF
  
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" hreflang="fr-FR">

}
 
?>